# How can we efficiently find the minimum integer from concatenating integers in an array?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, concatenation

Problem: Given an array of positive integers that can contain duplicates, find the minimum number obtained by concatenating the integers. Ex: `[3, 32, 321]` returns `321323`

Aside from trying all n! concatenation permutations, I can't seem to find a good way to solve this. I do know of a good solution below, but I'm having trouble understanding why it's true (**stop reading here if you want to try and solve this**):

I've a read a solution where we can sort the array with a comparator that compares two numbers `m` and `n` by comparing the numerical values of the concatenation `mn` and the concatenation `nm`, and the sorted array will be the concatenation that gives the mininum number, but I can't figure out why this is true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something similar to bubble sort to solve this.

- First, we notice that the length of the final result is fixed.
- Second, the result is the minimum lexicographical string that you can create (as the length of all possible string is fixed, so the minimum lexicographical is also the minimum number).

Assume that we have two number `n` and `m`, and if nm < mn, so n should always be in front of m. Because if we have a string is m...n, so we can always obtain a smaller string by swapping this into n...m.

So we continue to swapping number until nothing can be swapped, and this is the final answer

Comment: "Because if we have a string is m...n, so we can always obtain a smaller string by swapping this into n...m." You have the right intuition, but this statement does not hold in general. Consider m = 12 and n = 1 and ... = 3.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat you are right, there is something missing. As all elements in the `...`  should also obey the rule, so we have the final result... still need to improve :)

Answer (score 1):

Let `<'` be the comparator in question, so that `m <' n` if and only if
`mn < nm`. *Assuming that `<'` is a [strict weak
ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)*,
the other answers are on the right track about why sorting by `<'` is a
good idea. Here’s a careful proof. Suppose to the contrary that two
(possibly nonadjacent) input strings `m <' n` are out of order, so that
the output looks like

```
...n...p...m...
```

By induction on the distance between `n` and `m`, we show that this
output is not the minimum. In the base case, when `n` is next to `m`, we
can swap them. Since `mn < nm`, the new output is smaller. Inductively,
let `p` be an input string appearing in the output between `n` and `m`.
If `p <' m`, then `p <' n` by transitivity. If `p <' n`, then we invoke
the inductive hypothesis on `n` and `p`, which are closer than `n` and
`m`. If `n <' p`, then `m <' p` by transitivity. If `m <' p`, then we
invoke the inductive hypothesis on `p` and `m`, which are closer than
`n` and `m`. If none of these cases applies, then `n` and `p` are
incomparable, and `p` and `m` are incomparable. By the transitivity of
incomparability, `n` and `m` are incomparable, which contradicts the
fact that `n <' m`, so one of the preceding four cases applies.

The order of the input strings in the minimum output hence is determined
up to permuting equivalent strings within an equivalence block. Since
`m` equivalent to `n` implies that `mn = nm`, we get the same output
regardless of the permutation, and this output is thus minimum.

The interesting part of the correctness proof to me is proving that `<'`
is a strict weak ordering in the first place. In fact, it’s not unless
we exclude the empty string, which wreaks havoc. For all nonempty
strings `m`, let `key(m)` be the infinite string consisting of `m`
repeated infinitely often. To show that `<'` is a strict weak ordering
on nonempty strings, it suffices to show that `m <' n` if and only if
`key(m) < key(n)`.

Suppose first that `m <' n`. Then `mn < nm`. Letting `|m|` be the length
of `m`, we have `(m^|n|)(n^|m|) < (n^|m|)(m^|n|)` by repeated
application of the inequality `mn < nm`. Since
`|m^|n|| = |m||n| = |n^|m||`, we conclude that `m^|n| < n^|m|` and hence
that `key(m) < key(n)`.

Suppose now that `m <' n` does not hold. If `nm < mn`, then we argue as
before that `key(n) < key(m)` and hence that `key(m) < key(n)` does not
hold. Otherwise, `mn = nm`. Since `(m^|n|)(n^|m|) = (n^|m|)(m^|n|)`, we
conclude that `m^|n| = n^|m|` and thus that `key(m) = key(n)`.

Comment: Though the proper ordering just feels "obvious" to me, this is a good proof.  As for the empty string, it cannot affect ordering: you may place empty strings anywhere in the result with no effect.  Therefore it can be excluded.  (Also, this specific problem deals with numbers, for which there is no empty string representation. )

Answer (score 0):

This is more a math problem than a computer problem.

Define the concatenation operation as C(a1, ... an), where (a1, ... an) is an ordered array. Then C satisfies that

C(a1, ... an) = C( C(a1, ... ax), C(a(x + 1), ... an) )

for any 1 < x < n.

Using Mathematical Induction, define F as a function working on array of n variables.

F(2) = min(C(a1, a2), C(a2, a1)) is well defined.

For F(n), given F(n - 1) is minimized, the problem becomes to find the best position for an so that F(n) is minimized. Then it's easy to show that

- For any ax that C(ax, an) > C(an, ax), C(a1, ... ax, an, a(x+1), ... a(n - 1)) < C(a1, ... a(x - 1), an, ax, a(x+1), ... a(n - 1)).
- For any ax that C(ax, an) < C(an, ax), C(a1, ... ax, an, a(x+1), ... a(n - 1)) > C(a1, ... a(x - 1), an, ax, a(x+1), ... a(n - 1)).

So the best solution is insert an at where C(ax, an) < C(an, ax) and C(a(x+1), an) > C(an, a(x + 1)). Thus the algorithm you described holds.

Comment: It doesn't seem at all obvious why there should be optimal substructure when the strings have different lengths.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Pick up math :)

Answer (score 0):

If they were all single digit numbers, the solution is simple: sort them and pick the smallest digits for the most significant (leftmost digits) in the result.  e.g. pick 2 before 3 cause 23 is less than 32.

Similar for multi digit numbers, sort by leftmost digit.  e.g. pick 123 before 45, since 12345 is less than 45123.

The trickiest part is for ties.  If the leftmost digit is the same, compare the 2nd digit, then the third...  e.g. pick 321 before 34 since 32134 is less than 34321.

Finally, what if there is a tie and you run out of digits?  Pick 321 before 3 since 3213 is less than 3321.

So, using Java as a language, write a Comparator using these rules (note that you are probably better treating the numbers as Strings, not numbers), sort, then concatenate.  Other languages would be similar.

**Java code for the Comparator:**  [See also Gist with a main() for testing](https://gist.github.com/MorganConrad/dae68853c2854c7a0c58)  Note that I was able to reorg and simplify the rules.  This code can probably be better optimized for speed.  (Note: assumes all the ints are first converted to Strings for efficiency)

```
public class SO25396760 implements Comparator<String> {

   @Override
   public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      int minLength = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());
      int result = s1.substring(0, minLength).compareTo(s2.substring(0, minLength));
      if (result != 0)
         return result;

      int lenDiff = s1.length() - s2.length();
      if (lenDiff == 0)
         return 0;  // Strings are equal

      if (lenDiff < 0)
         return compare(s1, s2.substring(minLength));
      else
         return compare(s1.substring(minLength), s2);
   }
}
```

When input is {"321","3","35", "321334", "333", "2"}; the sorted array is
[2, 321, 321334, 3, 333, 35] 
and the concatenated value is
2321321334333335.  Test by inspection that this is minimal.

Comment: I don't think your approach is correct, for example, we have 321,3,35 and 321334, so in order to know which should be put in front, you need to generate all the possibilities :)

Comment: If these were words with letters, e.g. AT, ADD, BE, BUSY, do you need to generate all 24 possibilities?  No, because words beginning with A will always go before words beginning with B.  At most you have 4 possibilities, and by comparing the 2nd letter of ties you arrive at the solution with only one possibility.

Comment: How do you compare the case 3,33,333,3333,...? the point is with your algo, we are not sure how deep we need to go in order to compare two element. It will be more clear if you can write the pseudo code for your comparator.

Comment: Code added (Java Comparator, not sure what language OP wants...)

Comment: At best this comparator is a rather verbose way to get the same order as described in the question; no other order works (see my answer).

Comment: I guess you could just concatenate the two strings (in this comparator) and compare, but that's a lot of concatenation and object creation / garbage collection.  This code *may* avoid that.  (Some versions of Java do not allocate a new String on a substring, but I think newer ones do).